# Javascript issue, site works fine using localhost, doesn't work using computername

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iis

Ok so I'm having some strange issue with an mvc 3 site using javascript / jquery
hosted locally in IIS 7.5.

When I open the site through http://localhost/..... the site works perfectly in IE 9 and firefox,
when I use http://computername/..... the site doesn't work in IE. It does still work in firefox.

Looking to the script console using F12 and computername I see the following error:
SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number 
When I use localhost this error doesn't popup.

I've tried adding the site to the trusted sites in IE, this doesn't make a change.
Also I've used fiddler which shows all the needed javascript files are loaded correctly.

How can it be the difference in url obviously alters the way the javascript is interpreted?
What am I missing here?

Comment: The expected identifier, string or number is usually an error that means you have an extra unnecessary comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the problem probably IS the trailing comma:

One of the reasons may be that the document on computername loads the site in "Compatibility View". The trailing comma causes syntax error in IE7 document mode. Not other versions.

Check for extra commas!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I solved it,
apparently it has something to do with the compatibility mode in IE,
it automatically seems to go into IE7 mode for non-localhost domains.

adding this tag to the head of the page solved the issue:

> meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"

The next post describes a similar issue and how to solve it:
https://serverfault.com/questions/142721/iis-displaying-page-differently-when-localhost-is-used-in-url-vs-hostname

this article from the msdn specifies it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: That is a hack, not a fix. People in IE7 will still get the error. Make sure you find the culprit and fix it.

Comment: People still running IE7 really need to upgrade their browser ;)
but thanks for the warning

Comment: Relying on your audience to upgrade or conform to your standards is an absurd expectation. A lot of companies mandate certain versions, thus out of their control. Tailor your application to the greater audience, and embrace progressive enhancement

Comment: Since you are right I have checked all code for leading comma's and fixed the issue this way. The site still doesn't work well in an older version of IE due to the use of 'display:none' in the css.
Apparently this is also unavailable in IE7 Compatibility mode, so I've yet another solution to find :)

Comment: Don't you mean trailing commas? Accept my answer if it was correct :)